# OpenTK / OpenGL - Rotating camera with mouse

Tags: c#, vb.net, opengl, math, opentk

**Background**

I currently have an object that I am displaying that will always be at the origin. I have a function which increments my x and y angles and then calculates the new x,y,z coordinate for the camera:

```
Public Sub update_rotation()
    If cam.manual_lookat = True Then
        If camangley >= 360 Then
            camangley = camangley - 360
        End If

        If camanglex >= 360 Then
            camanglex = camanglex - 360
        End If

        If camangley < 0 Then
            camangley = 360 + camangley
        End If

        If camanglex < 0 Then
            camanglex = 360 + camanglex
        End If

        If camangley > 90 And camangley <= 270 Then
            cam.invert_y = True
        Else
            cam.invert_y = False
        End If


        camx = distance * -Sin(camanglex * (PI / 180)) * Cos((camangley) * (PI / 180))

        camy = distance * -Sin((camangley) * (PI / 180))

        camz = distance * Cos((camanglex) * (PI / 180)) * Cos((camangley) * (PI / 180))

        cam.Position.X = camx
        cam.Position.Y = camy
        cam.Position.Z = camz
        cam.lookat.X = 0
        cam.lookat.Y = 0
        cam.lookat.Z = 0

        ' Label2.Text = camanglex & "," & camangley
    End If

End Sub
```

I have this set up to use keyboard events.. the X button adds to the camanglex variable, the Y button adds to the camangley variable, and the Z button adds to the distance variable.

Everything works well doing it this way, using the keyboard.

**Problem**

I am trying to now use the mouse to handle the rotation instead of the keyboard. I believe this is simply a math question but how do I go about calculating either the new camanglex and camangley variables or directly calculating the new camx,camy,camz ones to establish my cameras new location?

I have a mouse function which will capture the mouse coordinates but am having trouble with the calculation part.

Comment: It's not really a math question, as you already have the heavy lifting done. What you need to know is how much the mouse has moved from frame to frame and use those values as the modifiers of `camanglex` and `camangley` much like you did for the keyboard input.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to orbit around object you could trace the path your mouse goes on fake sphere (which is called **trackball** sometimes). There is [a working example of orbit controls](http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit).

And here is a pseudocode sketch for something similiar:

```
mouseDownEventFunction(event) {
    computeDragPoint (event.mouseX, event.mouseY, &oldDragPoint);
    isMouseDown = true;
}
mouseUpEventFunction(event) {
    isMouseDown = false;
}
mouseMoveEventFunction(event) {
    if (isMouseDown) {
        computeDragPoint (event.mouseX, event.mouseY, &newDragPoint);
        rotateCamera (oldDragPoint, newDragPoint);
        oldDragPoint = newDragPoint;
    }
}
```

Here we find a point on trackball:

```
/* we want to ray trace a point on face side of fake sphere.
dragPoint* is our result*/

computeDragPoint(int x, int y, Vector3* dragPoint) {
    /* normalize x and y to [-1, 1] so they match flat circle position on screen.
    And assign this to dragPoint->x and dragPoint->y. 
    This part depends on what you want to achieve and input units of x, y. 
    Keep in mind aspect ratio */
    dragPoint->x = (2*x/screenWidth - 0.5) * (screenHeight/screenWidth);
    dragPoint->y = 2*y/screenHeight - 0.5;
    dragPoint->x /= sqrt(dragPoint->x*dragPoint->x + dragPoint->y*dragPoint->y);
    dragPoint->y /= sqrt(dragPoint->x*dragPoint->x + dragPoint->y*dragPoint->y);

    /* Then having two values in [-1,1] compute corresponding z */
    float tmp = dragPoint->x*dragPoint->x + dragPoint->y*dragPoint->y;
    if (tmp > 1) {
        dragPoint.x /= sqrt(tmp);
        dragPoint.y /= sqrt(tmp);
    }

    dragPoint->z = -sqrt (1 - dragPoint->x^2 - dragPoint->y^2) || 0;  
}
```

And rotation math can be done with quaternions (or just matrices from Euler angles if you don't want to use quats):

```
rotateCamera(oldDragPoint, newDragPoint) {
    Quaternion quat = new Quaternion (Config.AngleX, Config.AngleY, Config.AngleZ);
    quat.normalize();

    Quaternion deltaQuat = new Quaternion();
    deltaQuat = deltaQuat.setFromUnitVectors(oldDragPoint, newDragPoint);

    quat = quat.multiply(deltaQuat);
    quat.normalize();

    Vector3 resultAngles = Vector3();
    resultAngles.setFromQuaternion(quat);

    setCameraPositionFromAngles(resultAngles);
}
```

And in **setCameraPositionFromAngles(resultAngles)** set your final X, Y, Z coordinates by applying [three basic rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to your initial camera position. So your main parameters are resultAngles. You renew angles and then set position.

Maybe [this working example](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MlfSz7) will explain better.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting to this but I am confused with your computedragpoint function.  When you have float tmp = dragPoint->x^2 + dragPoint->y^2 what does the -> operator do? Sorry but I am writing mine in VB .NET so am unsure about this?  How are the x and y variable being used in this function?

Comment: A->x means (*a).x here. I might mess in code since it's just pseudocode but i mean passing A by pointer and accesing its x member. And dragpoint here is a vector3 with x,y and z elements.

Comment: If I have           Private Sub computeDragPoint(x As Integer, y As Integer, dragPoint As Vector3)  Dim tmp As Single = dragPoint.X ^ 2 + dragPoint.Y ^ 2
        If tmp > 1 Then
            dragPoint.X /= Sqrt(tmp)
            dragPoint.Y /= Sqrt(tmp)
        End If

        dragPoint.Z = -Sqrt(1 - dragPoint.X ^ 2 - dragPoint.Y ^ 2) OrElse 0  End Sub which is what I think you mean, where are the variables x and y being used that are inputs in the function?

Comment: oh yes sorry it is in /* commented part */. I didn't write it. Sorry for this unclear thing. That depends on what your x and y are and what radius of trackball do you want. If your have x in [0, width] and y in [0, height] you could try dragPoint.X = (2*x/width) - 1 and dragPoint.Y = (2*y/height) - 1.

Comment: I am sorry but that is confusing to me. Could you please edit your answer?  I have a variable "distance" that is the distance from the camera to the origin which could also be my radius of the sphere. I should have a function, much like you did, that I can input my mouse coordinates and then it outputs my x, y, and z angles.. which then I can use the same method I used prior to calculate the new x, y, z coordinate for my camera.  I do apologize for asking this but for some reason I am having a lot of difficulty on this last part.